# Unable to page AceCalhoon in Chat?

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

Whenever I try to page [AceCalhoon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/77/acecalhoon) in chat using the command `@@77@rpg.stackexchange.com` I get the message `@@77@rpg.stackexchange.com - SomeOtherName does not have a profile on rpg.stackexchange.com`. I also have a similar problem adding him to a room manually.

How can I page Ace?

Comment: Maybe it was because I hadn't associated my chat account with this site yet? You might give it another try, now that I've actually ensured that I can log into chat :-P

Comment: all sorted now, then?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, it works now that he logged in, but I think there is an unhandled edge case in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this since it looks resolved.

If the issue persists let us know.